# MJS - Array to ArrayList

Tags: arrays, arraylist

How do I convert an Array to an ArrayList in MJS?

So, let's say that I have an Array:
`MJS-Array;createnew. myArray`

When I do
`MJS-ArrayList;createnew. myArrayList -> through;myArray.`
this returns an empty ArrayList.

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about programming in a secret language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I figured out the answer.

We need to do
`MJS-ArrayList;createnew + { myArrayList ->  \[{ through;myArray. }] }`

Ew. Long and ugly. I can't believe that there is no better way to do this.